# Scapy installation fails due to invalid token

Tags: python, terminal, installation, scapy

I have recently taken up learning networks, and I want to install scapy.
I have downloaded the latest version (2.2.0), and have two versions of python on my computer- 2.6.1 and 3.3.2. My OS is windows 7 64 bit.

After extracting scapy and navigating to the correct folder in the terminal, I was instructed to run "python setup.py install". I get the following error-

> File "setup.py", line 35
>   os.chmod(fname,0755)
>   ................................^
>   ......................invalid
>   token

(dots for alignment)

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Update: `scapy-python3` is deprecated (2018) and will no longer be updated. `scapy>=2.4.0` has merged python 3 compatibility.**

**The most up-to-date installation method is now**

```
pip3 install scapy>=2.4.0
```

You may check the [installation page in the documentation](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-scapy-v2-x) for other installation methods

**Original answer:**

Perhaps you are trying to install the package scapy for Python 2, but you need the one for Python 3.

```
pip install scapy
```

gave this error:

```
os.chmod(fname,0755)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

while

```
pip3 install scapy-python3
```

did a proper install.

This error means the octal number is not recognized by Python 3, see [PEP 3127](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/#abstract):

> octal literals must now be specified with a leading "0o" or "0O" instead of "0";

Comment: I'm using `pip` in a Python 3 virtualenv and still get this error; even using `pip3` gives me this.

Comment: FYI. I got a "failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-yoan66gu/scapy-python3/" with runnign the pip3 install scapy-python3

Comment: `pip3 install scapy-python3` works fine, thanks.This is not addressed in the documentation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

The following works for me on Python 3.5

```
pip3.5 install scapy-python3
```

Comment: Thanks this one worked for me. The other solutions rest gave me errors.

Comment: I am using Anconda. `pip install scapy-python3` worked for me.

Comment: @anamritraj: Best answer for me!

Answer (score 4):

Change os.chmod(fname,0755) to os.chmod(fname,0o755) and re-run

Answer (score 0):

If `pip` installation is causing problem. You can download using `wget` and try to install.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget --trust-server-names scapy.net
$ unzip scapy-x.x.x.zip
$ cd scapy
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Check [here](http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-scapy-v2-x) for all ways of installing scapy.

Answer (score -2):

Scapy mainly used on uinx-liked OS, and can't install by pip. But they offered msi installer for windows:

http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html

The error also occurs on Linux, but virtualenv saves me.Virtualenv is a really good solution of using different version python or librarys on one OS.

```
virtualenv -p $python_bin_path $virtualenv_directory_name
```

Creating a virtual env with python2 and python3:

```
virtualenv -p `which python` project_with_python2
virtualenv -p `which python3` project_with_python3
```

Then active the env, and install the requirements.

```
cd project_with_python2
source bin/activate
pip install scapy
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And using deactivate to exit env.