# pip install scapy getting SyntaxError: invalid token

Tags: python, pip, scapy

I am getting the following error when trying to sudo pip install scapy, can anyone help?

```
sudo pip install scapy
Collecting scapy
  Downloading scapy-2.3.3.tgz (1.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 1.1MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-uuv1l4x3/scapy/setup.py", line 36
        os.chmod(fname, 0755)
                       ^
    SyntaxError: invalid token

    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you mean `scrapy` or `scapy`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scapy installation fails due to invalid token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138575/scapy-installation-fails-due-to-invalid-token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138575/scapy-installation-fails-due-to-invalid-token) !
Try fixing it using the recipes suggested, see if it works.

Comment: I do apologize, first off, I don't know how to modify to Oo755, as when I run the command, it creates a new temporary location and run setup.py. I am running off someone else's script which runs this command to install scapy, and it is working for other peoplse's machines. That's why I am trying to figure if there something else i can check, say I set up the environment wrong somehow?

Comment: @TheTeaRex I've just tried installing it on my pc and it errored out with the same message. The I tried `sudo pip2.7 install scapy` and it worked fine. I guess the problem is that the lib is not compatible with Python3

Comment: @TheTeaRex Okay, would you please then post the part of the script responsible for installing the lib?

Comment: you are absolutely right, I assumed I was running pip2.7, but apparently that script was changing it to pip3.4. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to install `scapy` and not `scrapy` then you can follow [this](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#installing-scapy-v2-x) recommended guide to download it. I believe the pip package is not the recommended way of installation.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget scapy.net
$ unzip scapy-latest.zip
$ cd scapy-2.*
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not my script. I am not able to modify the script to use this method to install instead. As part of the script, it runs sudo pip install scapy.